# React native onEndReached called across components

Tags: react-native

I have two separate components. The first is using a FlatList and the second is using a SectionList.

When I navigate from the first to the second component and trigger the "onEndReached", it ends up being called on both components.  Why would this be?

```
<FlatList
                key={'PostFlatList'}
                data={posts}
                ListHeaderComponent={
                    <PostListHeader 
                        type={props.type || route.params?.type}
                        options={options} 
                        addOption={addOption} 
                        types={constants.postTypes} 
                    />
                }
                extraData={extraData}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.listContentContainer}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
                onEndReached={({ distanceFromEnd }) => {
                    console.log("handleOnEndReached");
                    if (distanceFromEnd < 0) return;
                    if (posts.length > 0) addOption({lastRecord: posts[posts.length-1]._id});
                }}
                refreshing={refreshing}
            />
```

SectionList:

```
<SectionList
                key={'ProfileSectionList'}
                sections={sections}
                keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
                renderItem={SectionItemBuilder}
                renderSectionHeader={SectionHeaderBuilder}
                onEndReached={({ distanceFromEnd }) => {
                    console.log("handleOnEndReached");
                    if (distanceFromEnd < 0) return;
                    if (posts.length > 0) addOption2({lastRecord: posts[posts.length-1]._id});
                }}
            />
```

Comment: what do you mean by navigating between component? are you changing screen or are you just scrolling to the next component?

Comment: I am using react navigation to navigate from the first component to the second.  navigation.navigate(...).  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/

Comment: I fixed it by using https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused/.  I check if the component is focused before getting more data.

Comment: @BuffaloDev this is not an ideal solution as it rerender your view.

I have the same issue but only on the Web.